# variable is set to undefined in function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a slide show where I load the next slide before the current one is done. I have two prototypes for this. One for showing the current slide and then one for loading the next slide.

It worked fine until I put a `setTimeout()` for a delay between the slides. The `NextSlide()` function is calling itself after the `setTimeout()` however then the `this.nextSlide` is undefined even if it's loaded and added to `this.nextSlide` successfully in `LoadNextSlide()`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Set width and height of canvas
    var width = $(document).width();
    var height = $(document).height();
    $("#MKslide").css({"width":width+"px","height":height+"px"});


    slideShow = new SlideShow(width, height, "2d");
    slideShow.LoadNextSlide(null);
    slideShow.NextSlide();
});

function SlideShow(canvasWidth, canvasHeight, dimension){
    //Creating the slideshow
}

SlideShow.prototype.LoadNextSlide = function(currentSlideNumber){

    var data = $.parseJSON($.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/cms/php/request.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {slideNumber : currentSlideNumber},
        async: false
    }).responseText);
    this.nextSlide = data;
    alert(this.nextSlide.id);
}

SlideShow.prototype.NextSlide = function(){
    alert(this.nextSlide.id);
    this.currentSlide = this.nextSlide; //Swap to next slide.
    if(beginsWithHTTP(this.currentSlide.data)){
        this.image.src = this.currentSlide.data;
    }
    else{
        this.image.src = "http://" + this.currentSlide.data; //Set the current slide.
    }
    this.LoadNextSlide(this.currentSlide.id); //Preload next slide
    window.setTimeout(this.NextSlide,this.currentSlide.duration * 1000);//wait x seconds before swapping
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `bind(this)` as follows:

```
window.setTimeout(this.NextSlide.bind(this),this.currentSlide.duration * 1000);
```

`setTimeout` schedules the function to execute later, and at that time the context in which it is executed will always be the global object (`window`), instead of your object. And this context is what `this` refers to. The [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method creates a new reference to your method that will override this behaviour and will always run with `this` set to what you pass to `bind`, independent of the context that it was called from.

An alternative, but less elegant solution is to pass `setTimeout` an anonymous function in which the method is called explicitly from your object's context:

```
var that = this; // keep a reference to your object
window.setTimeout(function () {
    that.NextSlide(); // use the reference to your object
}, this.currentSlide.duration * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .bind or asign self=this and call a function anonymous with self.nextslide it is about scopes. Also you can use underscore bind as it would act as polyfill too.